# Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'prove_id' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT prove_id from provinces where prov_name='CENTRAL_PROVINCE'");
$m1 = $this->db->$query1->result_array();
```

when i run this i get a error like this.
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'prove_id' in 'field list'

SELECT prove_id from provinces where prov_name=CENTRAL_PROVINCE.
please help with this

Comment: Please add table definition.

Comment: It essentially means you don't have a field like prove_id. Can you share the output of 'desc provinces'.

Comment: It may be `id` or `prov_id` instead of `prove_id` (typo) :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that means you are trying to fetch a column which is not exist in your database table. please check your table and check column name for id and putt it in your query. like this-

```
$query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT field_name from provinces where prov_name='CENTRAL_PROVINCE'");
$m1 = $this->db->$query1->result_array();
```

Comment: i have that column in my db

Comment: please share output screen with error and your query